# Parse dataframe column for substring and return value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, string-matching, string-parsing

I have dataframe with a column called 'INFO' containing a string delimited by a semicolon like below. I would like to parse the string to return values corresponding to specific substrings and assign it to a new column.

EX. In the table below, I would want to assign the value (after the equals sign) for 'CLNDISDB' to a column of the same name.

I have tried:

```
df['INFO'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

which assigned each string part to a new column but that would still require me to parse each column for the necessary string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**I can only use python standard libraries**

```
|    | INFO                                              |
|----|---------------------------------------------------|
| 0  | AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619;... |
| 1  | AF_ESP=0.00015;AF_EXAC=0.00010;ALLELEID=514926... |
| 2  | ALLELEID=181485;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:... |
| 3  | ALLELEID=514896;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:... |
| 4  | AF_ESP=0.00515;AF_EXAC=0.00831;AF_TGP=0.00339;... |
| 5  | AF_ESP=0.40158;AF_EXAC=0.37025;AF_TGP=0.33886;... |
| 6  | ALLELEID=556509;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:... |
| 7  | ALLELEID=556512;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:... |
| 8  | ALLELEID=171289;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C4015293,OMIM:... |
| 9  | AF_EXAC=0.00001;ALLELEID=171288;CLNDISDB=MedGe... |
| 10 | AF_ESP=0.00038;AF_EXAC=0.00036;AF_TGP=0.00060;... |
| 11 | AF_ESP=0.00987;AF_EXAC=0.00772;AF_TGP=0.01558;... |
| 12 | AF_ESP=0.00070;AF_TGP=0.00080;ALLELEID=446981;... |
| 13 | AF_EXAC=0.00038;ALLELEID=446941;CLNDISDB=MedGe... |
| 14 | AF_EXAC=0.00114;AF_TGP=0.00958;ALLELEID=364282... |
| 15 | ALLELEID=556516;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C3808739,OMIM:... |
| 16 | AF_EXAC=0.00024;ALLELEID=364148;CLNDISDB=MedGe... |
| 17 | ALLELEID=514900;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C3808739,OMIM:... |
| 18 | AF_EXAC=0.42418;AF_TGP=0.28255;ALLELEID=133759... |
| 19 | ALLELEID=364285;CLNDISDB=MedGen:CN169374;CLNDN... |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fun, so setting up the dataframe

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test={'INFO':['AF_EXAC=0.42418;AF_TGP=-0.28255;ALLELEID=133759', 'foo','AF_EXAC=-0.42418;AF_TGP=0.28255;ALLELEID=133759']}
df=pd.DataFrame(test)
```

we get

```
    INFO
0   AF_EXAC=0.42418;AF_TGP=-0.28255;ALLELEID=133759
1   foo
2   AF_EXAC=-0.42418;AF_TGP=0.28255;ALLELEID=133759
```

Now using a lambda function and a conditional we just extract the values for "AF_TGP".  Setting up a new column, we extract the number from the regex pattern that surrounds the value.  But we only run the regex when it will pass the text, using the `in` function in python.

```
df['a'] = df['INFO'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'AF_TGP=(?P<number>[+-]?\d+\.\d+);', str(x)).group('number') if 'AF_TGP' in str(x) else np.nan)
```

this gives the result

```
    INFO                                            a
0   AF_EXAC=0.42418;AF_TGP=-0.28255;ALLELEID=133759 -0.28255
1   foo                                             NaN
2   AF_EXAC=-0.42418;AF_TGP=0.28255;ALLELEID=133759 0.28255
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Works well, have to clean up the results a bit and remove an extra space and comma.

```
def my_func(x):
    return  [value.split("CLNDISDB=",1) for value in x.split(';') if 'CLNDISDB' in value]

df['CLNDISDB'] = [my_func(x) for x in df['INFO'].values]
```